# Tabbar fixed:bottom. Buttons shift right slightly after transition from portrait to landscape

Tags: tabs, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

Worklight 6.1 Dojo 1.9

Created a ScrollableView with a tab bar fixed:top with two buttons, and a tab bar fixed:bottom with three buttons. When the application starts the tab bars, and buttons are centered correctly for both top and bottom.

Test scenario for both Android emulator, and Nexus 7 device:

1) In portrait mode the application initializes, and the main view shows both tab bars with
      buttons centered correctly.

2) Rotate the device to landscape mode, and both tab bars transition correctly.

3) Rotate back to portrait mode, and the tab bar fixed:top transitions correctly, but the tab bar
      fixed:bottom buttons shift right slightly.  Repeating the portrait -> landscape
      transition a second time causes additional shifting right.  After the second shift the 
      bottom tab bar remains fixed at that location.

```
  The tab bar fixed to the top behaves correctly during all mode transitions.
```

Appreciate any advice you can provide.

Comment: Do you reproduce the issue when loading the html in the browser instead of packaging it as a cordova app ?

Comment: here's a link to the code I tested: http://pastie.org/8751331

Comment: Built the app with common, and Android in Workight. Android emulator using Chrome the tabbar buttons remain in the correct positions across portrait to landscape transitions.  Next, I began stripping out code from my page by activitiy to isolate what my issue could be.  I've isolatedit down to::   <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" data-dojo-props="fixed:'bottom',barType:'segmentedControl'">  It appears  barType:'segmentedControl' causes the bottom tabbar in your sample codeto shift right but the top tabbar remains correctly positioned.  Appreciate any advice you may have on behavior.

Comment: Limited on space in previous comment.  Added barType:'segmentedControl' to your sample code and recreated tabbar shift in Android Emulator using Chrome.

Comment: Ok, I reproduced too. Investigating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following piece of CSS does the trick in my tests (including on Android):

```
<style type="text/css">
.mblTabBar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```

For the future, to avoid the need of this workaround, I registered https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17764.