# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Dojo Back button not adjusting to device orientation

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

Using a Nexus 7 tablet running Android 4.3.

In my application, the `Main` view has two tabbar buttons fixed top, and three tabbar buttons fixed bottom. The device is in portrait mode.

When selecting a button the View transitions successfully. The new view has a back button defined.
If rotating the device to landscape and then selecting the back button, then when the transition back to the `Main` view completes, the `View` (Buttons) are displayed as though the device is still in portrait mode (shifted left).

If I rotate the device back to landscape and back again to portrait, the view is corrected.

Questions:

1. Should the device + browser have adjusted for the change in orientation when the "back" button was selected, or is that the responsibility of the application?
2. If it is the responsibility of the application can you please provide advice on the best practice to impelement this support?

Note:  [I have another question relating to the centering of tabbar buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787463/tabbar-fixedbottom-buttons-shift-right-slightly-after-transition-from-portrait) during a change in orientation.  No buttons are selected.  This post resulted in a dojo defect being opened, and the suggested  work-around eliminated the issue. "Tabbar fixed:bottom. Buttons shift right slightly after transition from portrait to landscape"  My feeling is the two scenarios are *not* related since this new scenario corrects itself by rotating the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will qualify this as a work-around that was acceptable for my situation, but may not be for others based on anticipated appearance. I attempted both suggestions above, resize, and CSS but with no change in results. I found that by adding in an additional proprtrty "fill"  it brought focus to the tabbar during orientation change, and corrected the view.  I've spoken to some dojo experts, and have filed as a bug for review.

data-dojo-props="barType:'segmentedControl', fill:'always'"

Answer (score 0):

The best way (IMO) to handle orientation changes is through RWD ([Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)), more specifically [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to reposition the layout depending on the screen width. This is much faster than registering callbacks for orientation change events.

However some complex Dojo widgets like the Charting will not respond to media query properly, requiring orientation change events to force the widget resize.

To address your questions more specifically:

1. If you use media queries properly, the view layout will be resized accordingly depending on the device orientation but some complex widgets will require orientation change events to force a redraw
2. I would recommend reviewing the [IBM Worklight Best Practices for mobile app development](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/best-practices.html), which covers this topic among others.

I hope that this information will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

What we do right not to make sure that all components are correct, is to run a resize after transition in.

```
dojo.subscribe("/dojox/mobile/afterTransitionIn", afterTransitionIn);

function afterTransitionIn(view, moveTo, dir, transition, context, method) {
     currentView = view;
     currentView.resize();
}
```